# Is it possible to add classes to Parse Cloud Code?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have these classes I want to add to my Parse Cloud Code:

```
   function Rule = {
    this.accessor = new Accessor(); 
    this.act = new Action(); 
}

Rule.prototype.sendEmail = function(email, threshold, bill){
    if (this.accessor.check(threshold, bill)){
        this.act.actionTake(email, threshold, bill); 
    }

}; 

function Accessor = {

}

Accessor.prototype.check = function(threshold, bill){
    return bill > threshold; 
}; 

function Action = {

}

Action.prototype.actionTake = function(email, threshold, bill){
    //send email code 
};
```

but when I do add it to the very top of the javascript file

I get `Update failed with Could not load triggers. The error was Uncaught SyntaxErrorL Unexpected token in main.js:1`

Is Parse Cloud Code just for defining background jobs and cloud functions? Is it possible to add "class" definitions to Parse Cloud Code?

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var Rule = function()  {
    this.accessor = new Accessor(); 
    this.act = new Action(); 
};`

or

`function Rule() {
    this.accessor = new Accessor(); 
    this.act = new Action(); 
}`

basic js syntax, nothing related to parse

Comment: Thank you :D. I'm writing a simple java script file I don't know any java script.